# TensorFlow 2.0 - How to create a worker? Cluster

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cluster-computing, tensor

I'm new to Tensorflow, I want to perform distributed computing/training using different machines.

The tutorial in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#multi-worker_configuration) mentions:

> In practice, users would create **multiple workers** on external IP addresses/ports, and set TF_CONFIG on each worker appropriately.

I didn't find anything that tells how to do that.

I did find tutorials that used an old version of TensorFlow, but there was no TF_CONFIG there and I don't see any ClusterSpec used in the example, so I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simpler than expected.

Set the same `TF_CONFIG` on all machines and then run the same script on all machines.

The training does not start until all nodes/workers are connected.